Probabilistic methods
Let $n>cm\sqrt{\ln m}$ where $c$ is a large constant. For $1\leq i\leq n$, let $u_i\in\mathbb{R}^m$ with $\|u_i\|\leq 1.$ We have a fixed vector $z=(z_i)\in[-1,1]^m$ and a random vector $x=(x_i)\in\{\pm 1\}^m$ with $\mathbb{P}[x_i=1]=(1+z_i)/2$ and $\mathbb{P}[x_i=-1]=(1-z_i)/2.$ Coordinates are mutually independent. Prove that $$\mathbb{P}[|u_i\cdot(x-z)|\leq \sqrt{n},1\leq i\leq n]=1-o(1).$$
My attempt:
I tried to use Cauchy's inequality $\|u_i\cdot(x-z)\|\leq\|u_i\|\|x-z\|\leq \|x-z\|.$ And we only need to prove $$\mathbb{P}[\|x-z\|\leq \sqrt{n}]=1-o(1),$$ which is equivalent to $$\mathbb{P}[\sum (x_i-z_i)^2\leq n]=1-o(1).$$
The distribution of $(x_i-z_i)^2$ is: $$(x_i-z_i)^2=\begin{cases}
(1-z_i)^2 & \mathbb{P}=(1+z_i)/2\\
(1+z_i)^2 & \mathbb{P}=(1-z_i)/2
\end{cases}$$
How to proceed? Or is using Cauchy's inequality wrong at the beginning? Plus, I always found handling such inequalities of the sum of random variables difficult. What are the useful tools?
THX:)
BTW: this is ex 13.6.5 of Alon's 'The Probabilistic Method'
